# Safely storing encrypted sensitive data 'publicly' online?

Tags: security, encryption, aes

**How can I *safely* store sensitive data online?**

I want to store some extremely sensitive information online in a public folder, and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Specifically, I want to store bitcoin private keys in a .json file named "walletData.json" in a public folder. The file contains the wallet address and public key in plain text, along with an encrypted version of the private key.

Assuming anyone can access the file and attempt to crack the encryption password with their "super computers", what's the best way to safely encrypt that private key?

I know a longer password would be a good start, but ideally I don't want to *need* a password longer than 10 characters.

I was thinking of maybe hashing the password 1000 times, then using that hash+password as an AES encryption key. But, as everyone can see the key generation method, i'm not sure that will help? I was also thinking of padding out the encrypted private key with some other random data, but again, I don't know if it'll really help??

Is there a safe way to do this?

**EDIT - after Reid's answer:**

*I'm trying to do this 100% in Javascript/jQuery.*

When I export a CoinPrism.com wallet, I get this:

{"keys":[{"addr":"1PNLiLgW2fBokCB2wmfhZTtbmioitkqtMm","priv":"172655af193edeb54467a52fc6eb94c67eeeff8cd03555767e5cf12df694bb88f9c8b25c4019147d9e4993405274c96a","encryptionMode":"PKBDF2-SHA256","iterations":2000}],"salt":"2222b67fc7255aaf0b4027bfcabffb5e62f39e9e0aa13e8ad70f2dc75a484f26"}

The "priv" value is an encrypted private key. I don't know exactly how it's encrypted, but i'm sure that there's a way to decrypt it using just my 10 character password.

Does anyone know how they're doing this?

Is it safe to store this information online?

Comment: This would be better suited to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well, I will just say outright that *you* don't need to be the one who writes the code to do this — it is far too easy to mess up, and your post makes suggestions that are concerning. (For instance, you describe something of an ad-hoc key derivation scheme, but one that is insufficient in protection.)

So, you need a library of some kind to handle this business for you.

My suggestion: Use GPG with the ASCII armor option. For example:

```
gpg --symmetric --armor --cipher-algo AES file.txt
```

This will [symmetrically encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) (`--symmetric`) a file (`file.txt` here) using the AES cipher (`--cipher-algo AES`) and store the resulting encrypted file in an [ASCII armored format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) (`--armor`). *Note:* the resulting encrypted file will be stored in the filename plus the extension `.asc`; e.g., here, it puts the result in `file.txt.asc`. You can change this with the `--output` option.

Now, the above command will prompt you for a passphrase — this passphrase needs to be very strong, far more than 10 characters I'm afraid. This is the burden of passphrase-based encryption: you need passphrases that are strong. Ideally, you want a passphrase that is long and complicated, hard-to-guess and hard-to-bruteforce.

Since we are on StackOverflow, you may be looking to automate the passphrase entry (using scripting). To do that, there are several `--passphrase` related options for GPG. For example,

```
gpg --batch --passphrase "test" --symmetric --armor --cipher-algo AES file.txt
```

will use the passphrase `test` instead of prompting the user. Command line arguments are not safe, however, on a system, so it would be better to use the `--passphrase-from-file` option, which takes a single file as an argument. The first line of that file is the passphrase to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should have specified that my application is 100% clientside JS. Also, I can't encrypt the whole file, only the private key can be encrypted.